# Retorno de dados do Java para o Ajax utilizando Json

Tags: jquery, java, json, rest

Tenho uma aplicação Java, e um módulo que insere produtos na base utilizando REST. Na base o id do produto é autoincremental, e assim que eu adicionar o mesmo na base, preciso do id para que a tabela com os produtos sejam atualizado com o id corretamente.
Seguem os códigos:

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/minhaaplicacao/rest/produto',
        data: dataJson,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                **//aqui preciso pegar o ID, pelo objeto 
                    //que foi adicionado na base de dados
                    //e retornar para o novoId.
                    //o commit true atualiza a tabela no html, 
                    //inserido o novo registro, o novoId 
                    //é o valor que preciso pegar, 
                    //o qual foi inserido na base** 
                commit(true, novoId);
        }, 
        error: function () {
            commit(false);
            alert('deu erro');
        }
    });
```

No lado do servidor eu tenho o java retornando um response com o objeto produto, com todas as informações inseridas no banco:

JAVA:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response adicionar(Produto produto)
{
    Produto produtoInserido = ProdutoService.insert(produto);
    return Response.ok().entity(produtoInserido).build();
}
```

Ocorre que, o id do produto é auto incremental, e eu tenho o valor apenas depois da inserção, e preciso do mesmo retornando para o ajax, para que a tabela de listagem de produtos seja atualizada com id correto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas no retorno, coloque um parametro, como mostro no ex abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/minhaaplicacao/rest/produto',
        data: dataJson,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                    TEUID = r.Id
        }, 
        error: function () {
            commit(false);
            alert('deu erro');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Valeu Rod, foi muito útil. E resolveu meu problema, obrigado.

Comment: Poderia mostrar onde foi que colocou um parâmetro? Não consegui identificar.

Comment: success: function(PARAMETRO) { }